# Having an issue escaping a string being sent to a shell command

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook that executes a shell command containing a token which contains a '.'

The command works fine when I run it manually from a bash shell and place the token in double quotes. (also works without any quotes)

I've tried every possible escape approach as well as the quote filter and nada.

```
 # Token Format
 [a-zA-Z0-9]{6}.[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}
```

Here is where I'm running the shell command:

```
- name: Bootstrapping compute nodes
  vars:
    server: "{{ hostvars[groups['masters'][0]]['bootstrap_server'] }}"
    token: "{{ hostvars[groups['masters'][0]]['bootstrap_token'] }}"
    hash: "{{ hostvars[groups['masters'][0]]['bootstrap_hash'] }}"
  shell: cobbler join {{ server }} --token "{{ token }}" --hash "{{ hash }}"
  register: bootstrap_cmd_output
  when: ('compute' in group_names)
```

I know the variable is intact at the beginning of this play by using a debug statement.

I've tried these approachs:

```
  shell: cobbler join {{ server }} --token \"{{ token }}\" --hash "{{ hash }}"

  shell: cobbler join {{ server }} --token \\"{{ token }}\\" --hash "{{ hash }}"

  shell: cobbler join {{ server }} --token {{ token | quote }} --hash "{{ hash }}"
```

When I try no quotes at all it complains:

```
'asfcLs.' - invalid token
```

It's splitting the token on the '.'.

I've also tried all of the above using command instead of shell.

Any other tricks I can try?

Comment: What complains? Bash? Cobbler (whatever that is)? The thing cobbler is communicating with?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
token: "[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}{{'.'}}[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}"
```